# Android - pass text from one class to another class via textview

Tags: java, android, eclipse, class, textview

I am making a calendar/appointment app on android to develop my skills the opening screen has a calendar, a textview(dateselected) and a button(create). the textview(dateselected) displays the date selected by the user and the create button opens another class where the user fills in appointment details. this second class also has a textview(dateselected2)

how can i carry the text in the dateselected from first class to the dateselected2 in the second class.

i know how to pass data with in a class but im finding it hard to do this among 2 classes. any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send data from one Activity to another using Intent:

StartActivity.class

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MyNewActivity.class);
Intent.putExtra(MY_STRING_KEY, dataselected.getText());
startActivity(i);
```

NewActivity.class

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
super.onCreate(savedInstance);

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String text = extras.getString(MY_STRING_KEY);

    dataselected.setText(text);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(class1.this,class2.class);
myIntent.putExtra("user_date", yourStringName);
StartActivity(myIntent);
```

Now, in your second class in onCreate try:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
myStringName = (extras != null ? extras.getString("user_date") : null);
```

Comment: do i put the first part in the buttons action listener?

Comment: if the button starts your second activity then yes

Answer (score 0):

really simple

in first activity use

```
intent.putExtra("data", dateselected2);
```

and in second activity use

```
String data = getIntent().getExtras().getString("data");
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html